# How to create variable includes in Text Template Transformation Toolkit files?

Tags: c#, t4

I want to generate slightly different partial classes using .tt files.

```
// using statements here; the same for both Cat and Lion
namespace House.Pets {
    public partial class Cat  {
        // lots of code here; the same for both Cat and Lion
    }
}
```

and

```
// using statements here; the same for both Cat and Lion
namespace City.Zoo.Animals {
    public partial class Lion {
        // lots of code here; the same for both Cat and Lion
    }
}
```

The key is that if any of the code or using statements needs to be changed, the change should be made manually in only one place.

I can accomplish this with tt include directives, like the below.  But I'm wondering if there is a way that uses either a variable that is passed down to the included file, or some kind of search and replace.

```
<#@ include file="$(SolutionDir)/FelineUsingStatements.t4" #>
namespace House.Pets {
  public partial class Cat {
<#@ include file="$(SolutionDir)/FelineCode.t4" #>
```